# H2 Database fails to find existing column

Tags: sql, h2

My Configuration file:

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

my data.sql script is something like :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (
   ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   vname varchar(255) not null
);

INSERT INTO people(vname) VALUES ('Chuck Norris');
```

When this is executed, INSERT fails with error :
cannot find 'VNAME' column.

1. Why is the column name auto all capsed? does that affect my INSERT command?
2. I just created the table, why cant INSERT find vname column?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yeah, I just had to disable dll autogeneration.

Comment: Ahh, so it was recreated by the persistance framework without vname. Tricky one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Did you perhaps already create the table PEOPLE without the VNAME column? Your SQL won't touch it if the table already exists. Remove the database files and try again...

Comment: Already did that, I created people table with vname right off the bat.